# Postgres/Aurora query response time unexplained

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, aws-aurora

I have AWS Postgres Aurora RDS version 11 running with db.r6g.12xlarge instances in a 3-node cluster with 1 writer, 2 readers. It should be noted though that this also occurs on our on-premises Ubuntu/PostgreSQL v11 instances as well but it’s using more RAM and with huge page settings on, so it happens more frequently with less dramatic drops in response time.

We run a bunch of read-only functions on the readers and have noticed a saw-tooth pattern for response time for a bunch of these queries where durations will increase for some time and usually a couple times a day, will suddenly drop, and start to increase after that.

My first thought was auto vacuum/analyze operations, but we log those and I see no unusual number of tuples or pages cleared or any tables analyzed any differently that would explain it.  Live/dead tuples do not suddenly drop either, nor is table bloat impacted.  Cache hits remain the same as well.  There aren’t any additional checkpoints being done, nor any uptick in sequential scans either.  Freeable memory is the same, and no SwapUsed memory is used either.

We also run a nightly VACUUM (ANALYZE) on all tables but this drop seems to occur even outside when these are running.

I’m looking for what could explain this behavior, and what metrics (either Postgres or AWS) I could use beyond what I have already looked at to trace this as we would like to understand what’s causing the sudden drop in performance at random times.

Comment: Not nearly enough information. Presumably the "response time" you measure includes the network overhead. So, do you monitor the network traffic changes? Do the longer queries perhaps return more data? Do the query execution plans change?

Comment: I expect this is due to vacuuming.  Your evidence against it doesn't seem very persuasive to me.  The fact that you vacuum overnight doesn't mean much, unless that is the *only* time vacuuming ever happens.  And I do not expect the contents logged by log_autovacuum_min_duration, for example, to be very useful for this purpose.  More useful would be the timing: does the time of the when the vacuum finishes on the master correspond to the timing of when the performance improves on the replica?

Comment: Knowing the the slow queries are doing could be very useful.  Try to turn track_io_timing to on on the replica, then use auto_explain to do the equivalent of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) for the slow queries.  Or just run a query manually with EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) during a time period when it is being slow.

Comment: @mustaccio Response time is actually query duration, as reported by Postgres itself via pg_stat_user_functions.total_time.  No network latency.  The same queries run returning roughly the same data, just the time it takes to do so dropsa for an unknown reason.

Comment: @jjanes we are logging vacuum and analyze activity and can tell when its completed and how long it took,  It's not lining up with when we see performance improvement.  Are there any other metrics we could track to tell us if something is being vacuumed at the time without being logged?  I never said it isn't vacuuming, but would like to prove it is.

Comment: _No network latency_ -- how so? Your function won't complete until the client application fetches every last one of the rows it returns, so the `total_time` must include the network transfer time plus whatever latency the application introduces between every fetch.

Comment: Setting log_autovacuum_min_duration = 0 should cause every autovacuum to be logged (which can be overwhelming).  I don't think that there is a feasible way to cause every manual VACUUM to be logged, you just need to rely on knowing all your code/jobs which would invoke those.

Comment: @mustaccio this is because we are also collecting metrics for response times from pg_stat_user_functions itself to report the time it takes, we are not taking this time from the client.  Also we capture all execution plans so we can see the time there itself has dropped.